# Handling Ruby Standard Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, standard-error

I'm using the FedEx gem to pull down tracking numbers, the issue I'm running into is that if a tracking number has been generated, but not picked up, the gem returns a `Fedex::RateError`

According to the documentation `Fedex:RateError` inherits from `StandardError` I need to display a message if this error trips on the frontend site

I looked around online and found some ideas, but was hoping someone can point me in the right direction for handling errors, I'm using Rails 4.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I'm not clear on what the actual question is.

Comment: What did you try so far? This question is so trivial I have no idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin
  # Do your normal happy path view stuff here
rescue Fedex:RateError => error
  # Do your display of the error to the user here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks msergeant, that did it!

Here's my final code- this recovery isn't very well documented and seems like a handful of people we're looking for it.

```
begin
  results = fedex.track(:tracking_number => tracking)
rescue Fedex::RateError
    statusImg = "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRuKAIYZ2mNLsjRulsH05zNwF93jmAdpgZGSgtVN8XiT7_SWw285g"
    statusRet = "Nope!!"
    @trkResultTxt = statusRet
    @trkResultImg = statusImg 
else
    tracking_info = results.first
    @trkStatus = tracking_info.status
end
```